# build url's in java in xpages

Tags: java, xpages

in xpages I can use:

```
var protocol = context.getUrl().getScheme() + "://";
var url:XSPUrl = new XSPUrl(database.getHttpURL());
var host = url.getHost();
...
```

to build urls to documents/files in documents

How should I build the URL's equivalent in Java?

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down.  This is a very valid question.  I've often thought of creating a Java URL Cheatsheet to go along with my SSJS version.

Comment: the XSPUrl class is also available in Java. You should be able to set the same things like host, scheme, path, parameters etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I build URL's in Java all the time.

Here are some RANDOM code snippets that I use.  This is not a single class, just random snippets that should help you get started at least.

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
XSPContext context = XSPContext.getXSPContext(facesContext);

String entryPage = context.getUrl().getPath() + context.getUrl().getQueryString();

if (entryPage.contains("/home.xsp")) {
    this.console("Entry Page contains /home.xsp");
    if (this.isBasicMode()) {
            entryPage.replace("home.xsp", "basic_Menu.xsp");
        }
    } else {
        this.console("entry page does NOT contain /home.xsp");
    }

context.redirectToPage(“/myPage.xsp”);


public void redirectExternal(String url) throws IOException {

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExtenalContext externalContext = fc.getExternalContext();
        externalContext.redirect(url);

    }

public void redirectToPage(final String pageName) {
        // pageName = "/myPage.xsp"

        try {
            // You'd think this would end all Java processing but that's NOT
            // what happens
            // It looks like the Java code will finish and only then will the
            // redirection happen.

            final String entryPage = JSFUtil.getXSPContext().getUrl().getPath() + JSFUtil.getXSPContext().getUrl().getQueryString();
            FrameworkUtils.getSessionScope().put("entryPage", entryPage);
            this.setEntryPage(entryPage);

            JSFUtil.getXSPContext().redirectToPage(pageName);

        } catch (final RedirectSignal rs) {
            // Ignoring this error. Useless!
        }
        // Returning false so we can stop the calling code from continuing
        // return false;

    }

    public String getParam(final String key) {
        if (!this.getQueryString().containsKey(key)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return this.getQueryString().get(key);
        }

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Map<String, String> getQueryString() {
        final Map<String, String> qs = (Map<String, String>) FrameworkUtils.resolveVariable("param");
        return qs;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks David, actually I borrowed after my question post some code from your MWLug repo which helped me. Thank you very much for posting your answer here!

Answer (score 1):

depends where your documents files are. It think the best way is create a servlet in the nsf, call that by passing an docUNID and attachmentName. Then you can get the document and write the attachment as stream to the response. If you set the header to attachment, like

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+attachment.getName()+"\"");
```

you will get the attachment as download

Comment: Hi Frank, that was not exactly what I was looking for (I want to build url's to files which I would like make available as links to users) but your suggestions is useful in some other use-cases. Thanks for answering!